# how to set cmd(DOS) in php

Tags: php, cmd

I figure out how to execute the input to the cmd program with php using exec function ('cmd.exe')
most of the tutorials available on the internet suggest execute commands using the command line argumen.tapi cmd.exe (DOS) does not have a command line argument

so basically I want to set the (DOS) program like cmd enter input into it without having to use a parameter cmd argument, as we typed directly into cmd itself.

I made a (DOS) program using C ++ language, I want a program that can be run in php website without having to create a parameter in advance, as we typed directly into the program, live stream

**code that I use**

```
<?php
$inputcmd = $_POST['inputcmd'];
$output = shell_exec('cmd.exe $inputcmd');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
<form method="POST" />
<input type="text" name="inputcmd" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

dos program that I created does not have prameter, so I want to type directly into it blends into the input output php

Comment: There hasn't been a "DOS" for decades :-)

Comment: Perhaps add `DOS` tag?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generally get `cmd` to execute your code as arguments if you use something like:

```
C:\Users\PaxDiablo\Documents> cmd.exe /c "echo hello"
hello
```

That's from an actual command interpreter window but the same rules apply anywhere you can run `cmd.exe`.

I *suppose* I don't need to mention that it's a spectacularly bad idea to allow some random Joe to execute arbitrary code on your server. So, if you haven't thought that through, give it at least a *couple* of minutes.

Comment: @nasa, isn't that what _I_ said? :-)

Comment: the above code runs.  C:\Users\PaxDiablo\Documents> cmd.exe /c ipconfig